# for each loop with json data

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm having a small problem while pulling tide data from the wunderground api. When I use the code below to pull the time of day for low tide I get an accurate answer one day, but a wrong answer the following day:

```
<?
$json_url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/b2b4a1ad0a889006/tide/q/NJ/Wildwood.json';



// jSON String for request
$json_string = '[http://api.wunderground.com/api/b2b4a1ad0a889006/tide/q/NJ/Wildwood.json]';

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,



);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

$parsed_json = json_decode($result); 

$parsed_data->stats; //this returns


$low_tide_time = $parsed_json->tide->tideSummary[8]->date->pretty;
echo $low_tide_time;



?>
```

The reason for this is clear. The array key (in this case [8]) is not consistently assigned to the same tide data type (low tide) every day. So today [8] may be the array key associated with the time for low tide, but tomorrow [8] will be the array key assigned to sunrise, moonrise, etc.

Is there a way to use a for each loop to grab the time for low tide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is something unique in the $parsed_json->tide->tideSummary Object which belongs to your requested information (like "Title: Low Tide") you could do a foreach loop and check if that value is present.

Like this

```
foreach ($parsed_json->tide->tideSummary AS $tideSummary) {
if ($tideSummary->title == "Low Tide") {
      $LowTide = $tideSummary;
}
}
```

You can access the Low Tide data after that like this:

```
echo $LowTide->Date;
```

PS: Untested and no info about your JSON Format, if there is no unique information to identify Low Tide it could get tricky..

Comment: what about foreach ($parsed_json->tide->tideSummary AS $tideSummary) {
if ($tideSummary->data->type == "Low Tide") {
      $LowTide = $tideSummary;
      echo $LowTide;
}
}

Comment: @matt, you can't echo $LowTide as its still an object. See my edit how to get the values from it!

Answer (score 0):

I check JSON format and it should works:

```
foreach( $parsed_json->tide->tideSummary AS $tideSummary ) {
    if( $tideSummary->data->type == "Low Tide" ) {

        $low_tide_time = $tideSummary->date->pretty;
        echo $low_tide_time;

        // you can end of foreach
        break;
    }
}
```